# Best practices OO

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flex4

Ok, let's see the following scenario:

I have two classes. Schedule and Event.

One Schedule has many events. It's simple.

So, for get all Events, where I should leave the getAllEvents method?. Schedule Class or Event Class? Best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: If the Schedule has Events, and getAllEvents returns a list of Events, then it should be in Schedule ... I don't see how it'd even work if it were in the Event class, or perhaps I am confused ...

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to get all events for a given schedule, define a method called getAllEvents() in the Schedule object.

If you'd like to get all events - globally, across all schedules - I would encourage you to create an EventCollection object, and add all events to it - besides registering them in the respective Schedule.